# Why do I receive a different int then I've sent from using indy?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-2007, delphi-xe7

I've checked and when I convert the ints to hexadecimal they become 4C52 en 524C000000000000 respectively, so it looks as though the bytes are reversed.

The client runs on Delphi XE7 for android and the server runs on Delphi 2007.

How can I fix this?

Push code of client: `Client.IOHandler.Write(19538);`

Pull code of server: `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt64; //receives 5930114809340100608`

Answer (score 8):

You are not taking endian or byte size into account.

The integer overloads of `TIdIOHandler.Write()` accept a numeric value in **host byte order**, which may be either little-endian or big-endian depending on the platform, and will convert them for transmission to **network byte order** by default, which is big endian.  The integer `TIdIOHandler.Read...()` methods expect numeric values to arrive in **network byte order** by default, and will convert them to **host by order** by default.  So, if you are using Indy on both sides, you do not have to worry about this detail, since the endian of the reads/writes would be consistent regardless of which platform is on either end.

The `TIdIOHandler.Write()` numeric overloads, and the `TIdIOHandler.Read...()` numeric methods, all have an optional `Convert` parameter that is True by default.  If you set this to False instead, values will be sent/read in **host byte order** instead of **network byte order**.

What is more important is that you are reading an `Int64`, but you are not sending an `Int64`.  There are multiple overloads for `TIdIOHandler.Write()` for the various integer types, and an untyped `19538` constant would never resolve to `Int64` with such overloads present. So you need to use a type-cast to tell the compiler to use the `Int64` overload:

```
Client.IOHandler.Write(Int64(19538));
```

Or use a variable:

```
var
  Value: Int64;

Value := 19538; 
Client.IOHandler.Write(Value);
```

> Pull code of server: AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt64; //receives 5930114809340100608

19538 in hex is `0x4C52`.

5930114809340100608 in hex is `0x524C000000000000`.

Notice a similarity?

19538 in network byte order is `4C 52` as a 16bit integer, and as `00 00 4C 52` as a 32bit integer. That is only 2-4 bytes, but an `Int64` is 8 bytes, so there has to be another 4-6 bytes present otherwise `ReadInt64` would not return. But lets assume there were extra `00` bytes present (in which case you are not handling your protocol data correctly). In order for `ReadInt64` to return 5930114809340100608 from 8 bytes in network byte order, it would had to have received `52 4C 00 00 00 00 00 00`, which does not come close to matching 19538 as a 16bit or 32bit integer in network byte order.

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed it with code from http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.basm/fastest-best-way-to-reverse-byte-orde/1096017

It's  a swap function that uses assembly, so now my code looks like: `Swap8(AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt64);`

The Swap8 function is:

```
function Swap8 (i: Int64): Int64;  register;
asm
  mov eax, dword [i]
  bswap eax
  mov dword [Result+4], eax
  mov eax, dword [i+4]
  bswap eax
  mov dword [Result], eax
end;
```

Comment: You don't need a separate swap function.  The numeric `TIdIOHandler.Write()` and `TIdIOHandler.Read...()` methods have optional `Convert` parameters for dealing with byte swapping.

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong solution. Use the concept of host to network and network to host. Don't ever explicitly swap bytes in your high level code.